next-auth handling session expired from backend golang
i want to handle token expired from backend in next js and save the token in session next-auth and cookie , but i have the problem when the token from backend is expired , i have no idea to delete the token when every 401 response code from backend and redirect to login in the client side, this is my code , in this case i don't want to decode the token
import CredentialProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      id: 'credentials-1',
      name: 'Credentials-2',
      type: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { pn, password } = credentials
        try {
                   
          const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
          })

          const data = await res.json()
          if (res.status === 200) {
            return { ...data, credentialType: '1' }
          } else {
            throw new Error(JSON.stringify(data))
          }
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e.message)
        }
      }
    }),
    CredentialProvider({
      id: 'credentials-2',
      name: 'Credentials-2',
      type: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { pn, password } = credentials
        try {
         
         
          const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/login2`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)
          })

          const data = await res.json()
          if (res.status === 200) {
            return { ...data, credentialType: '2' }
          } else {
            throw new Error(JSON.stringify(data))
          }
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(e.message)
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  secret: 'Secret',
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60
  },

  jwt: {
    secret: 'Secret',
    encryption: true
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: {
      'credentials-1': '/login',
      'credentials-2': '/login2'
    }
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.credentialType = user.credentialType

        if (user.credentialType === '1') {
          token.name = user.data.data_user.name
          token.email = user.data.data_user.email
          token.pn = user.data.data_user.pn
          token.status = user.data.data_user.status
          token.branch = user.data.data_user.branch
          token.token = user.data.token
        } else if (user.credentialType === '2') {
          token.name = user.data.data_user.nama
          token.pn = user.data.data_user.pn
          token.role = user.data.data_user.role
          token.branch = user.data.data_user.branch
          token.token = user.data.token
        }
      }
      return token
    },

    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.name = token.name
        session.user.pn = token.pn
        session.user.branch = token.branch
        session.token = token.token
        session.credentialType = token.credentialType

        if (token.credentialType === '1') {
          session.user.email = token.email
          session.user.status = token.status
        } else if (token.credentialType === '2') {
          session.user.role = token.role
        }
      }

      return session
    }
  }
}

i have try to using to delete the cookie but doesn't work, this is my code to request from the client side to handle every request in next js using use server, so anyone to help me ?
'use server'

import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import { authOptions } from '@/libs/auth'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const CustomDispatch = async (url, req) => {
  try {
    const router = useRouter()
    const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
    const token = session.token
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      cache: 'no-store'
    }

    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/${url}`, requestOptions)
    const responseData = await res.json()

    if (res.status === 401) {
      const response = NextResponse.redirect('/login')
      const allCookies = cookies().getAll()
      allCookies.forEach(cookie => {
        response.cookies.set(cookie.name, '', { maxAge: 0, path: '/' })
      })
      router.refresh()
      return response
    }

    return responseData
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error)
    return null
  }
}

export default CustomDispatch

